# Reducing duration by a percentage in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been racking my brain for hours on how to do this, so I am reaching out to some of you excel experts.

Say you have a duration represented as 1d 14:25:00 and you want to reduce that by a given percent, such as 149.5%, how can this be done?

At first I thought about going down the route of having a cell formatted in time, but when you try and do math against it, it fails.

Then I thought about maybe converting the time down to seconds and working with that, but that seems like it is total pain in the rear. It involves a lot of converting from time to number then back to time to display it. There has to be an easier way.

Comment: If you reduce something by ~150%, you'll get a minus number i.e. x-1.5*x=>-0.5x  or in your example, about -19 hours. Is that what you expect? That would certainly be tricky, as you can't have a negative time value. Also is 1d 14:25:00 a string or a formatted datetime value?

Comment: I currently have my formatting set to [h]:mm:ss, however this causes me to enter the original time in hours, which isn't the end of the world. However having the actual time be returned would make more sense. So in our example if it showed 0d 19:25:00 would make more sense than a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you format the cell to read the Date/Time. If it's represented as a Time, then I believe the best approach is to convert the percentage into a decimal number (i.e 150% = 1.5), then use that in your formula.

However, it also requires applying the cell format to the custom format of [h]:mm:ss to include any times above 24 hours. See the image below for an example.

Time Conversion Example: [image]

The only alternative is a "pain in the rear" - breaking the time down into seconds.
Excel includes built-in functions to convert a Date/Time into HOUR(date), MINUTE(date), and SECOND(date). Unfortunately, getting the number of days requires calculating the difference between two times: DAYS(end_date, start_date). I used this in the example above for the rows titled *Conversion*.